# Flutter sample app not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, flutter

Today I started development in [Flutter](https://flutter.io/). I have completed setup and installation process. When I try to run sample app created by following steps mentioned [here](https://flutter.io/using-ide/#creating-a-new-project).

I don't know what can be problem/Issue.

But output look like this in Android Emulator.

[image]

Comment: Create an issue on flutter repository [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) as it's most likely a bug

Answer (score 4):

I assume it is an issue with hardware rendering in the emulator.

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12112

If it actually is the problem you should be able to work around with

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering -t lib/main.dart
```

(`-t lib/main.dart` is default and optional)

Comment: This is working with terminal but how to apply same thing from android studio. I mean how to resolve issue when i press run button from AS ?

Comment: I guess there is no way. You'll need to wait for the bug to be fixed.